# How to set up ACLs to allow users to access only specific records?

Tags: acl, loopbackjs

I'm planning to use Loopback to create an application where users will be able to access only specific records.

Let's say we have a `Projects` model, with 2 records:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "project_name": "foo",
            "project_start_date": "2012-10-29T18:25:43.511Z"
        },
        {
            "project_name": "bar",
            "project_start_date": "2012-10-30T18:25:43.511Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

and that I have 2 users, `joe` and `katie`.

I want `joe` to be able to access only project `foo`, and `katie` to be able to access only project `bar`.

Is this possible at all? If so, how should I go about setting up the ACLs?

Comment: I am also going through same problem.  what is you final solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the declarative ACL doesn't support your use case. You need to create afterRemote hook to further check the response. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+hooks.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Role that matched in the afterRemote hook?

Answer (score -1):

You can also play with dynamic roles. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Dynamicroles and similar loopback example:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/blob/master/common/models/project.json

Comment: The role resolver example is misleading and only really works when a single record has been requested. When doing a find(.) over multiple records the role resolver is less useful and the 401 returned on reject is not useful when you just want a filtered list of the projects that the user can access.