# loopback - append filter before get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback for a node JS app. Loopback auto generates the CRUD api. So, I was trying to alter one get api so also include a table. I can do this by adding include filter in query as

`/api/expensecategories?filter[include]=vendors`

but I want `/api/expensecategories` to return with the table. For that I used `beforeRemote()` method to change the request before.

My code for it is:

```
expensecategories.beforeRemote('find', function (ctx, inst, next) {
   console.log(ctx.req.url);
   ctx.req.url = "/?filter[include]=vendors";
   console.log(ctx.req.url);
   console.log('GET api called');
   next();
});
```

this is changing the request url but not changing the response, it is the same and table is not included. I tried changing everything in `req` like

`ctx.req.query = {filter: { include: 'vendors' }};`

but no use. Any idea how can i achieve this. Both tables relation is already defined and I am able to get the desired result by making a custom api like,

```
expensecategories.expensecategory = function (cb) {
    expensecategories.find({
      include: {
        relation : 'vendors',
      }
    }, function(err, data) {
    cb(null, data);
    });
  };

  expensecategories.remoteMethod (
    'expensecategory', {
       description: 'get all expense types + vendors',
       http: {path: '/yes', verb: 'get'},
       returns: {arg: 'expensecategory', type: 'string'}
    }
  );
```

So, my table relation and everything is correct. I want the same result for `/expensecategories` also. Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ExpenseCategory model default scope to include Vendor by adding a "scope" section:

```
"scope": {
    "include": "vendor"
  }
```

Comment: That works thanks:) but i need to edit query in req as have to get `user_id` from session. And help on that. I tried `beforeRemote()`.

Comment: It depends what you want it for - if it is for authentication then have you seen this question? `afterRemote` may be what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661968/how-to-set-up-acls-to-allow-users-to-access-only-specific-records.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the `find` remote path like this:

```
expensecategories.remoteMethod (
 'expensecategory', {
   description: 'get all expense types + vendors',
   http: {
     path: '/', // <-- HERE
     verb: 'get'
   },
   returns: {arg: 'expensecategory', type: 'string'}
  }
);
```

**Update** : this worked in previous Loopback versions, with current version you also have to do this, after `expensecategories.setup()` call :

```
expensecategories.disableRemoteMethod('find', true);
```

**Update2** : this is how you should setup your Model :

```
// This is automatically called by loopback
MyModel.setup = function() {
  // Super setup
  MyModel.base.setup.apply(this, arguments);

 // Your customization
  MyModel.remoteMethod(...);
  MyModel.disableRemoteMethod(...);
};
```

Comment: this will create a new api at `/expensecategories` instead of replacing the old of. Two api at same endpoint. And they both are responding the same. I have tried this.

Comment: This is weird because I've just tested it on a project and it worked.

Comment: `expensecategories.disableRemoteMethod('find', true);` this blocks both api calls. Then i get 500 error on custom api. Where do i have to call `expensecategories.setup()`. ?

Comment: I was referring to [this setup method](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+class#model-setup).

I don't remember where I saw this but I always put `remoteMethod` and `disableRemoteMethod` calls inside it.

The base setup is where your custom model will inherits from its base's remote methods.

I updated my answer with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is answered, but I arrived here from Google with similar problem because i wanted to add another filter parameter on query for all requests.

Thing with relation did not work for me, so i continued to dig and found this [snippet on access hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#access) in docs. So in the end i did this (based on your example):

```
expensecategories.observe('access', function (context, next) {
  context.query.where = context.query.where || {};
  context.query.where.include = 'vendors';
  next();
});
```